# sudo/conda/pip/PATH not found on Git Bash

Tags: bash, anaconda, windows-10, git-bash

What is the simplest course of action?

Is there an official install guide / link?

Literally nothing in my Git Bash is recognised, e.g.:

```
$ pip install pandas
bash: pip: command not found

% conda activate
bash: conda: command not found
```

```
$ set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
bash: C:UsersdabellAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython310: command not found

HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ PATH
bash: PATH: command not found

HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ export PATH="$PATH:"C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3

HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ conda list
bash: conda: command not found

HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ export PATH="$PATH:"C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3

HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ conda list
bash: conda: command not found

HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ export PATH="$PATH:"C:\Users\dabell\
> conda list

HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ conda list
bash: conda: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to just run the regular windows installer (from the python site - https://www.python.org/downloads/) and then add the [appropriate folder](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installation-steps) with the `python` and `pip` binaries to your $PATH [system variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

There are package managers like https://community.chocolatey.org/packages for windows, but as you can see they do not come as standard on windows.

Comment: Will try this out right now and get back to you

Comment: you might also want to rename the question to something like sudo/conda/pip not found

Comment: What do I do now with: `C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`?

Comment: thats the link under "system variable" in my answer

Comment: you add it to the path, but i might have to get a better answer to link instead, i just read the one i linked

Comment: you just need to add things to your path. reinstalling git bash wont help. you can even use bash tricks without restarting - e.g. if your conda path is C:\path\to\conda, you can just run this bash command for bash to find conda: `export PATH="$PATH:"'C:\path\to'`, and the `conda` command will start to work. there's most likely a standard folder which python installs all its commands into. for virtualenvs that folder is the one with the `activate` script (so: `virtualenv env1` means it adds `env1/bin/` to the path)

Comment: Check post for attempts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245661/discussion-between-dave-ankin-and-danielbell99).

Comment: to print path, you'd need to echo $PATH

Answer (score 0):

Git bash is just a shell/terminal client to Git, which does (and should) not know what are `su`, `apt-get`, `pip` or anything else, that has no association with git.

`su`, `apt-get` and etc. are utility programs, which you invoke from the shell, as commands, and which are available on Linux distributions;

`pip` is the package installer for Python.

`netstat`, as an additional example, is a utility software available on Windows OS, from the shell.

None of abovementioned will be available in your git bash, because, again - git bash is just a Git client, not a OS shell.

Comment: Ah sorry; I've removed these from the post

Comment: Thank you. Might you know where I go from here?